# SSH2 returning "resource(2) of type (stream)" (PHP)

Tags: php, ssh, libssh2

I'm attempting to run a SSH command from a remote server with PHP's `ssh2` library using the `ssh2_exec` function.

Instead of getting what I want returned back to me from SSH, I get this:

```
resource(2) of type (stream)
```

Sometimes the `2` is a `3` if that matters.

Here is the code that I'm attempting to use:

```
<?php

$connection = ssh2_connect('ssh.example.com', 22);

ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'password');

if($output = ssh2_exec($connection, 'uptime')) {

    var_dump($output);

}
```

---

**Working solution**:

```
<?php

$connection = ssh2_connect('ssh.example.com', 22);

ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'password');

if($output = ssh2_exec($connection, 'uptime')) {

    stream_set_blocking($output, true);

    echo stream_get_contents($output);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php):

> Return Values
>
> Returns a stream on success or FALSE on failure.

A [stream](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) is a file-like object. You can get data from it with [stream functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.stream.php) or file handle functions like [fread](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php).

E.g.

```
$string = stream_get_contents($stream);

$line = stream_get_line($stream);

$fivebytes = fread($stream, 5);
```

Comment: Never dealt with a "stream" before. How exactly would I go about getting the data from the "stream"?

Comment: @JoshFoskett: You can use [`stream_get_contents()`](http://php.net/stream_get_contents) to read the stream till the end.

Comment: echo(stream_get_contents($stream));

Comment: Thanks guys, I also had to add stream_set_blocking($stream, true);